# :Contains( '2 minutes').addClass also adds class to '12 minutes'

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have a few dynamic elements in a table and right now I am trying to add a class to the  if it contains '2 minutes' problem is that if another container says '12 minutes' is adds the class to that  as well. How can I just look for the 2 minutes and forget the 12 minutes?

```
$(".notice:contains('2 minutes')").addClass('highlight');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own filter function with strict comparison:

```
$('.notice').filter(function() {
    return $.text(this) === '2 minutes';
}).addClass('highlight');
```

If the required text is located within other text, you may use regular expression to test for validity, e.g. `/\b2 minutes\b/.test($.text(this))`.